# Write a program that takes 3 characters and then

Tags: python

I'm studying in Python and I get stuck at this one.

problem: Write a program that takes 3 characters and then counts the number of consonants and vowels as shown in the following example.
       Input three characters:> z H a
       The number of consonant is 2.
       The number of vowels is 1

here is my code that I've been trying

```
a,b,c = input("Input three characters:>").split()
a = str(a)
b = str(b)
c = str(c)
if a == 'a' or a == 'e' or a == 'i' or a == 'o' or a == 'u':
    print("The number of consonants is 2. The number of vowels is 1.")
    elif b == 'a' or b == 'e' or = b == 'i' or b == 'o' or b == 'u':
        print("The number of consonants is 2. The number of vowels is 1.")
        if c == 'a' or c == 'e' or = c == 'i' or c == 'o' or c == 'u':
            print("The number of consonants is 2. The number of vowels is      1.")
```

But it is too long if I consider if the vowels is 2 or more. 
How can I code it easier for this one?

Comment: Don't delete the code from your question.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of putting the characters in distinct variables, leave them in a list, and loop over that list.

Answer (score 0):

You can just check the member ship in a concatenated string of vowels :

```
if your_word in 'aeiou':
```

And if you are dealing with more words lo long strings you can out the vowels in a `set` container which has O(1) order for checking membership

Comment: That's help me a lot! I'll try with your solution.
Thank you

Comment: @xJelloMasterx Welcome, So if it was helpful you can tell this to community by accepting the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dict of vowels and then test to see if the inputs are in that dict:

```
vowels = {'Vowels':['a','e','i','o','u']}
a,b,c = input("Input three characters:>").split()
a = str.lower(a)
b = str.lower(b)
c = str.lower(c)
letters = [a,b,c]
voweltruth = [x in vowels['Vowels'] for x in letters]
print("The number of consonants is %i. The number of vowels is %i." % (3-sum(voweltruth),sum(voweltruth)))
```